# Angular 2 Pipe Events

Tags: angular, animation, events, pipe

I've created a custom Angular 2 pipe to filter an array based on the ID attribute inside objects. I'm just wondering which events, if any, exist for pipes, as I would like to add an animation when the filtered data is passed through the pipe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there are events to animate filtered data. You do have **:enter** and **:leave** on which you can apply CSS styles.

Here is a sample.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-selector',
  templateUrl: './templateFile.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./stylesFile.component.scss'],
  animations: [
    trigger('aliasesAnimation', [
      transition('* => *', [
        query(':enter', style({opacity: 0}), {optional: true}),
        query(':enter', stagger('50ms', [
          animate('250ms ease-in', keyframes([
            style({opacity: 0, transform: 'translateX(-20%)', offset: 0}),
            style({opacity: 0.5, transform: 'translateX(5%)', offset: 0.3}),
            style({opacity: 1, transform: 'translateX(0)', offset: 1.0})
          ]))
        ]), {optional: true}),
        query(':leave', stagger('50ms', [
          animate('250ms ease-in', keyframes([
            style({opacity: 1, transform: 'translateX(0)', offset: 0}),
            style({opacity: 0.5, transform: 'translateX(5%)', offset: 0.3}),
            style({opacity: 0, transform: 'translateX(-20%)', offset: 1.0})
          ]))
        ]), {optional: true})
      ])
    ])
  ]
})
```

Hope it helps, @T04435